Relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against `.bss' - Assembly x86-64 error

Assembler: NASM x86-64
Linker: GNU ld
Platform: Windows

I tried moving HANDLE type, from GetStdHandle function from Windows API, into quadword memory value and I faced this error: Relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against '.bss'.
I've made research and found out that most of the time, this error comes from bad sizes - moving invalid size values into register/memory. I can't really see how my code is supposed to fit in that issue.
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteConsoleA
extern ExitProcess

STACKMEM equ 32

section .data
    hello db "Hello, world!",10,0

section .bss
    written resd 1
    handle resq 1 ; quadword, should be enough to store whole RAX value

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, STACKMEM

    mov rcx, -11      ; std output
    call GetStdHandle

    mov [handle], rax ; error 1. here

    ; ... some other code ...

    mov rcx, [handle] ; error 2. here
    mov rdx, hello
    mov r8, 15
    mov r9, written
    call WriteConsoleA

        ; ... some other code ...

    mov rcx,0
    call ExitProcess

        ; not sure if this is needed
    add rsp, STACKMEM
    pop rbp

Microsoft documentation does not really say how big/small HANDLE type is (that's what GetStdHandle return value is) so I just tried putting it into smallest big enough memory slot, quadword.
The only mention of HANDLE (GetStdHandle return value type) in Microsoft WinAPI documentation is this:
HANDLE
A handle to an object.                      
This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
typedef PVOID HANDLE;

So HANDLE is pointer to void, yeah very helpfull...
I have also run following commands:
NASM -f win64 main.asm
ld main.asm -o main.exe -e _start C:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll

Good to mention that when I moved directly rax into rcx and print it out, it worked. Pushing onto the stack works as well but neither any of these method fits my need. Changing resq to dword, word, byte, octoword or changing mov [handle], rax to mov qword [handle], rax etc. didn't fixed my problem as well.

Put default rel at the top of your file or use [rel handle] everywhere.

Related for Linux: 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?
